# 80s Sci Fi game book with starship pilots coming together to complete a mission, maybe a race

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book from my childhood. It was from sometime in the early '80s. It was a game in an oversized book (almost a magazine), kind of like a cross between a *Choose Your Own Adventure* book, a tabletop RPG, and a giant comic book.

The premise was a group of starship pilots and their various ships coming together to complete some kind of a mission that I seem to remember as almost a race. One of the ships kind of resembled a BSG Viper, and another one was a big sphere, a third might have been star shaped. Along the way, several of those ships were destroyed.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Since you say it's like an RPG, you might want to also ask at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ ,

Comment: This sounds similar to a book I half remember - lots of spaceships, and they dropped out or were destroyed as the book went along - they might have appeared as black silhouettes or something? There was some kind of game element in identifying them? I'd love to know the name also.

Answer (score 3):

This could be *[Battle for the Ancient Robot](https://gamebooks.org/Item/1829/Show)*, a 1985 game book set from TSR.  It was for two competing players, each of whom actually had a separate illustrated book that they referred to, although actions taken by one player could also affect the other.  One the characters was a heroic human, the other an evil robot, and they were searching the galaxy for components of the titular robot.

[image: Book 1]

[image: Book 2]

The first time I actually played the game against someone, I died on my first turn.